# How to get both return code and output from subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, adb

While developing python wrapper library for Android Debug Bridge (ADB), I'm using *subprocess* to execute adb commands in shell. Here is the simplified example:

```
import subprocess

...

def exec_adb_command(adb_command):
    return = subprocess.call(adb_command)
```

If command executed propery *exec_adb_command* returns 0 which is OK.

But some adb commands return not only "0" or "1" but also generate some output  which I want to catch also. *adb devices* for example:

```
D:\git\adb-lib\test>adb devices
List of devices attached
07eeb4bb        device
```

I've already tried *subprocess.check_output()* for that purpose, and it does return output but not the return code ("0" or "1").

Ideally I would want to get a tuple where t[0] is return code and t[1] is actual output.

Am I missing something in subprocess module which already allows to get such kind of results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Popen and communicate will allow you to get the output and the return code.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT

out = Popen(["adb", "devices"],stderr=STDOUT,stdout=PIPE)

t = out.communicate()[0],out.returncode
print(t)
('List of devices attached \n\n', 0)
```

check_output may also be suitable, a non-zero exit status will raise a CalledProcessError:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError

try:
    out = check_output(["adb", "devices"])
    t = 0, out
except CalledProcessError as e:
    t = e.returncode, e.message
```

You  also need to redirect stderr to store the error output:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError

from tempfile import TemporaryFile

def get_out(*args):
    with TemporaryFile() as t:
        try:
            out = check_output(args, stderr=t)
            return  0, out
        except CalledProcessError as e:
            t.seek(0)
            return e.returncode, t.read()
```

Just pass your commands:

```
In [5]: get_out("adb","devices")
Out[5]: (0, 'List of devices attached \n\n')

In [6]: get_out("adb","devices","foo")
Out[6]: (1, 'Usage: adb devices [-l]\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for the broad answer!

Comment: @ViktorMalyi, no prob, you're welcome.

Comment: It should not be e.message, but e.output: [python2 doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError), [python3 doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError)?

Comment: In Python 2: `rc, out = commands.getstatusoutput("cmd...")`, In Python 3: `rc, out = subprocess.getstatusoutput("cmd...")`